# Where to ask a question related to technologies?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have seen in many posts that Stack Overflow is a site for programming discussion, and meta discusses the meta information of the site.

I have a question related to some technologies.

Eg: If OBD=II was invented for controlling vehicle emissions then why is it providing information related to chassis body power-source, etc.

Where can I ask these questions?

Comment: *Stack Overflow is a site for programming discussion*  you will find many more authoritative posts stating that SO is not for discussions and not a forum, but a Q and A site.

Comment: Your question sounds like it might be specific to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair. If so, then there might be [a place for it](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) on the StackExchange Network.

Answer (score 1):

@kojiro is right you can ask this one in the Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair Stack Exchange. Its first page says:

> Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for mechanics and DIY enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles. It's 100% free, no registration required.

I did a quick research in which it returned 55 questions tagged with [OBD-II](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bobd-ii%5D+is%3Aquestion).

So, if you are going to join that site, firstly, check if the question is not there yet, i.e, if it is a duplicate.